# Button in ExpandableListView

Tags: android, events, custom-controls, expandablelistview

I have custom `ExpandableListView`.
`ExpandableListView` layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout_nutrition_list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/background_dark" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/elv_nutrition"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:indicatorLeft="10dp"
        android:divider="@color/gold_color"
        android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Group layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingTop="5dp"
android:paddingBottom="5dp"
android:background="@drawable/lv_item_bg"
android:contentDescription="@null" 
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants">

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textColor="@color/gold_color"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:typeface="serif" 
    android:contentDescription="@null" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/btn_func"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/lv_item_bg"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:onClick="BtnCategMore"

    android:scaleType="center" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

How i can get access to parent view after click button `btn_func` ? I need get text from `textView1`.

Thank's for advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How you are attaching this groupLayout xml to your adapter..actually you have to implement method `getGroupView()` inside your `ExpandableListAdapter`. There you can inflate this layout and access all the views from this layout.

Comment: Thank you. Solved by adding setOnClickListener in getGroupView method.